# Prestashop 1.7 Translation in overriden controller

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

i have an overriden Frontcontroller

and since i did not know where and how to make a global new translation, after some research i made it so:

$module = Module::getInstanceByName('ekomiratingsandreviews');
   $ekomiText = sprintf(**$module->l(**'%s hat bei eKomi eine Bewertung von %s von 5 basierend auf %s Bewertungen.'), ''.Configuration::get('ERP_SHOPNAME').'', ''.$ratingsAvg.'', ''.$ratingsCount.'');

The ekomiratingsandreviews module i reference here, is more or less a convinient module where the translation can also be placed in. Im implementing and "ekomi feature" but which is not in the ekomi module itself, but its a global Text which is show in all views, thats why i made an override of the frontendcontroller, where i want to pass the ekomi text to smarty.

But i looked in the presta backend, and my translation string appears nowhere.
Thanks for help.

So my questions are
1) why does the translation not appear in the backoffice
2) how to easiely make a new "global" translation in presta 1.7 without using any module?!

Answer (score 0):

Try reload page, and clear cache via FTP (racine/var/cache).

Regards